# how to solve the following expectation? closed-form expression or approximation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients, convex-analysis

Suppose there is a binomial random variable $X\sim B(n-1,p)$,how to solve the following expectation $$E[(1- b^{X})^{m}]$$ where $b\in (0,1]$ and $m\in \mathbb{N} $ are all constants.
I have tried my best to solve this expectation and got the expression $$\sum_{i=0}^{m}\binom{m}{i}(-1)^{i}(b^{i}\cdot p+1-p)^{n-1}$$.Can I simplify it further?Actually I need an closed-form expression.

Comment: Since $a,b$ are small, could you perhaps round to 3 first terms? Then you need $1 - ma E[b^X] + m(m-1)a^2/2 E[b^{2X}]$...

Comment: I don't think that's what I want,but thank you anyway.

Comment: @saz yes, $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: One does not *solve* an expectation, one *computes* it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I know how to compute this expectation,but i need an expression of it.